Has anyone seen such a function/quantity?
I am dealing with a problem wherein I encounter the following quantity-
$$
Q_{d,  \epsilon}(t_0) = \sup_{t' \notin B(t_0,  \epsilon)}  \inf_{t \in B(t_0,  \epsilon)} \frac{d(t') - d(t)}{t'-t}.
$$
Here, $d(\cdot)$ is a non-negative convex function and $B(t_0, \epsilon)$ is the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $t_0$.
I am wondering whether anyone has seen or come across this quantity or something similar to this. Any helpful resources will be appreciated.

what is $d(t)$ ? what is $B(t_0,\epsilon)$?

I edited the question to add the necessary details.
